# How to create a Node JS Server

Tags: node.js, server

I need help to create a few node js servers. 
One server should read from aws dynamodb (like once every minute), one should read data from a api, like once every day. 
Like cronjobs.

My problem here is how I should write an application that is running 24/7. Iam guessing `while(true){doStuff()}` is wrong?

Comment: I know this is old question, if someone need help in 2021, nice explanation video is there : https://youtu.be/KEZdvF1sADg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply run your node.js script as a daemon using [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever)

and then you can use setInterval to run a js code every x seconds.

Another approach is really using cronjobs that run the scripts you want every minute, whatever suits your needs better :)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a zero downtime production process manager called [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2).
I run my nodejs server using pm2 in my company, and I didn't face any downtime in 3 years.

Microsoft, paypal, IMB uses pm2. [Check here](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/users/).

Using this module is dead simple:

Step 1:

> npm install pm2 -g

Step 2: cd to main file of nodejs. app.js is this file(or www)

> pm2 start app.js

That's it.
Once set up, your server will run without any zero downtime. Make sure you hit

> pm2 list

to cross check if your application has correctly started.

Comment: Thanks, looks very nice. Maybe overkill for me, don´t know yet, but i will try it out.

Comment: Its dead-simple to use. Check my update.  pm2 was primarily built for node js. Remember nodejs is a single-threaded app. If you code catch any exception, none of the http request will be listened and your server will be down.